# RFT testscripts not executing

Tags: mainframe, rft

I have just installed RFT version 8.3.0 for testing a mainframe application. I imported the appropriate rftjdtr files to the project. But i am unable to execute any of the testcases. When i press the run ( or debug) button, nothing happens. There are no error messages popping up. I suspect it is a java configuration issue on my machine. I have tried comparing the settings with another machine where it is working fine. It is the first time that i am using RFT, so i do not know what to do. Can somebody please help me with this?

Comment: You're licensed to use the product. The license includes support. Contact your internal support team (there is no reason that you should have been left on your own to install this) and they will either sort the problem out for you, or contact IBM for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue. This may be because of workspace error. Create a new workspace and run the script.